# Save data to database in Baqend

Tags: baqend

I can't seem to figure out how to update data in the database:

Here is the code:

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var fulladdress = this.state.address1 +" "+ this.state.city +", "+ this.state.state +" "+ this.state.zip;
    Geocoder.getFromLocation(fulladdress).then(
      json => {
        var location = json.results[0].geometry.location;
        //alert(location.lat + ", " + location.lng);
        var geo = new db.GeoPoint(location.lat, location.lng)
        var updatecompany = new db.Companies({
          id: '16747fce-f0b1-422b-aa60-220c2dccac58',
          name: this.state.name,
          logo: '',
          photo: '',
          address1: this.state.address1,
          address2: this.state.address2,
          city: this.state.city,
          state: this.state.state,
          zip: this.state.zip,
          geo: geo,
        });

        updatecompany.update().then(() => {
          alert("company saved!")
        })
      },
      error => {
        alert(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

In this file I'm looking to update the data of a company profile.  First we are getting the lat/long from Google Maps API.

When I run this I get this error: Unhandled Rejection (EntityExistsError): The entity /db/Companies/16747fce-f0b1-422b-aa60-220c2dccac58 is managed by a different db.

I tried removing the ID, but then I get this error: Unhandled Rejection (PersistentError): New objects can't be inserted.

Do I need to be using key or something else?  Or does the id passed outside of the object or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify existing objects, you should get the existing object from the db and then modify it. This ensures that no update is lost by an overwrite.

```
db.Companies.load(id).then(company => {
     company.name = this.state.name;
     ...
     return company.update();
});
```

Alternatively you can just get the managed db object apply your changes and force save it. This will overwrite any existing database state and just save your changes.

```
//This will get the current managed object for the Id
//That object may not have loaded state
company = db.Companies.ref(id);
company.name = this.state.name;
//The force overwrites any previously stored state
//This may result in lost updates when the object is concurrently saved by different clients
company.save({force: true});
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying here... just to clarify: baqend is only going to update the key/values we pass?  So in your example, that would just update the company.name?  And also I should not pass empty strings because we only need to pass what is going to be changed?

Comment: This worked great, I was thinking you have to build an object then somehow pass it back to baqend, this way is much simpler!

Comment: If you have beforehand loaded the object by a find or load call, the ref just returns this previously loaded object. So updates can afterward easily be applied.